# Dojo ON ENTER event does not fire

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a button:

```
var cmdZAll  = dom.byId("zall");
```

The on click and focus events work:

```
on(cmdZAll,  "click", function(evt) { alert("zoom all click"); });
on(cmdZAll,  "focus", function(evt) { alert("zoom all focus"); });
```

But the enter event does not work:

```
on(cmdZAll,  "enter", function(evt) { alert("zoom all enter"); });
```

Why is that?

Thanks for any help,
Gido

Comment: Dont think there is an onEnter, you would either use keydown, keyup or keypress.  you can then check the event.keyCode

Comment: Yes, you are right.  That was a misunderstanding on my part.  Thanks for the note.